# Is there a general solution to the water-bucket logic problem?

Tags: algorithms, puzzle

Having an infinite supply of water and two containers, one for 3 liters and one for 5 liters, how would you measure 4 liters?

Each step in the solution can be one of three things: Fill up a container all of the way, empty a container completely, or use one container to fill up another as much as possible.

The solution to the original problem is:
Fill the 5 litre bucket (completely). The buckets are now 5/5 and 0/3.
Pour the 5 litre bucket into the 3 litre one. They are now 2/5 and 3/3.
Empty the 3 litre bucket. They are now 2/5 and 0/3.
Pour the 5 litre bucket into the 3 litre one. They are now 0/5 and ⅔.
Fill the 5 litre bucket. They are now 5/5 and ⅔.
Pour the 5 litre bucket into the 3 litre one. They are now 4/5 and 3/3.
Now, you have one bucket with the required amount of 4 litres.

Is there a standard algoritm to determine a possible solution, or even the shortest solution?

Comment: Relevant: [Making the water gallon brainteaser rigorous](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648282/)

Comment: @MJD: Wow,  impressive answer! At least I know it's possible, now I should give it some more thought.

Comment: I think I can prove that any reasonable solution looks like the one there: the search space is a simple loop, and the only reasonable thing to do is to proceed around the outside of the loop until you reach the target position and win, or return to the start position, in which case winning is impossible.  (Note the interesting invariant that in any minimal solution, at all times a bucket is full or a bucket is empty.) But I can't finish the proof before work; maybe later.

Comment: Also relevant: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/645845/relatively-prime-property-verification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look
[How not to Die Hard with Math](https://youtu.be/0Oef3MHYEC0)
or
[Lecture 7.5 - Case Study: the Water Pouring Problem (31:45)](https://www.coursera.org/learn/progfun2/lecture/EkEqR/lecture-2-5-case-study-the-water-pouring-problem)
and, for example, corresponding GithubGist
[Scala: water pouring problem solution]gist.github.com /hanbzu /7302266 "concise & clear code"

Comment: While information at these links may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.

Comment: I agree, it will be nice, but it is too hard to give a short answer for a general solution . Because of that those links .

Comment: Then don't give a short answer: posts here can be up to 30,000 characters long.